# How to format a number in Java and also keep the decimals?

Tags: java, format

I'm trying to show milliseconds as seconds while also keeping the decimals e.g. I have 1234 milliseconds and I want to show this as 1.234 seconds.

```
Decimal duration = 1234;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
String durationStr = formatter.format(duration / 1000);
```

Any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: You already have some good answers, but to address your actual question: you can't "format a long and keep the decimals" since a `long` doesn't have any decimals. You need to instead compute a value of a type which does have decimals, and format **that** value.

Comment: True, but the answers already solved that problem as well because the end result is a string.

Comment: My point is that the issue in your code has nothing to do with strings or formatting; you are doing those parts correctly. Your issue instead was with primitive math. The question as written (and your comment above) suggest you may not realize this.

Comment: If it makes you happy I'll change it to Decimal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a double to divide the number `1000d`.

```
String durationStr = formatter.format(duration / 1000d);
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you should be using `BigDecimal` - create a `BigDecimal` from the long, and then scale it by 3 places:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(duration).scaleByPowerOfTen(-3);
String durationStr = formatter.format(bd);
```

By using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`, you know that you'll still have *exactly* the value you're really considering, rather than simply "the nearest approximation that `double` can hold".

You may well also want:

```
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
```

... to ensure that you always get exactly 5 digits. (Assuming you want 1 second to be "1.000" for example.)